# Trac logo and favicon 404

Tags: trac, mod-python

This is going to read similar to the other Trac static resource issues I found (pretty well encompassed by [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9629887/trac-logo-issue)), but this doesn't appear to be the same issue.

I have partial (non-root) access to a server with other Trac projects, and I have the ability to create my own Trac site.  The server has the following software versions:

- Python 2.7
- Trac 1.0
- mod_python 3.3.1

**So I've created and have been using the site for a few weeks, but I can't get the logo or the favicon to show up.**  There is another Trac project to which I have access, and to make sure I wasn't missing anything obvious I compared the trac.ini files from both projects.  The relevant sections have very similar settings, e.g.:

```
[header_logo]
src = site/my_logo.png

[project]
icon = site/favicon.ico
```

and those are both sitting in their respective Trac environments' htdocs folders:

```
/
  opt/
    trac/
      trac_env_1/
        htdocs/
          my_logo.png
          favicon.ico
      trac_env_2/
        htdocs/
          my_logo.png
          favicon.ico
```

**However, the images only appear on one site but not the other**.  On my site Google Chrome says:

> GET https://{Intranet URL}/trac/{my_trac_env}/chrome/site/my_logo.png 404 (Not Found)

I have tried the following, all of which have been unsuccessful:

- Setting the width and height inside [header_logo] to the correct dimensions
- Copying the exact same images that work on the other project over to my project
- Changing `site/favicon.ico` to `/favicon.ico` and `/favicon.ico?` (as suggested on the [Trac wiki](http://trac.edgewall.org/wiki/TracInterfaceCustomization))
- Running `trac-admin deploy .` in place, copying the images to htdocs/common, and changing the trac.ini setting to `common/my_logo.png`
- Changing `site/my_logo.png` to `/images/my_logo.png` and matching that folder structure in my trac environment.
- Making an htdocs/site/ folder and adding the logo to it (which, I know, is what other people did wrong, but I'm banging my head against the wall here).

The only thing left I can think of is Apache settings, but from what I can tell it should handle whatever Trac environments it can find in /opt/trac.  In /etc/httpd/conf.d/trac.conf, it has:

```
<Location /trac>
SetHandler mod_python
PythonInterpreter main_interpreter
PythonHandler trac.web.modpython_frontend
PythonOption TracEnvParentDir /opt/trac
PythonOption TracUriRoot /trac
PythonOption PYTHON_EGG_CACHE /var/trac/egg-cache
</Location>
```

That it uses TracEnvParentDir instead of just TracEnv is the important bit, I think.

So, I am at a loss.  Please, can somebody help me?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Gah, I *knew* I was missing something simple.

**The problem was file permissions**.  Apache did not have read access to my Trac environment, so a simple `chmod -R a+rX /opt/trac/trac_env_2` solved it.

I guess that's another answer to the "My static files won't show up in Trac" question:

1. Don't make an actual folder named "site" in your Trac environment; `site/my_logo.png` will look in `trac_env/htdocs`
2. Make sure your server knows where to find your Trac environments.  Both mod_python and mod_wsgi settings for this are easily found.
3. Make sure your server has read access to your particular Trac environment (`chmod a+rX` to give directories-only execute permission)

Just posting here in case anyone else runs into a similar issue.